# Load of generic .csv files into SQL Table using BulkCopy

Tags: c#, datatable, sqlbulkcopy, columnmappings

I am trying to create a generic module that will load .csv files into SQL tables.  The SQL tables are already created and their names, and the name of the file, will be passed as parameters.  This what I have so far...

```
    public void Main()
    {
        var mFilepath = Dts.Variables["InputFile"].Value.ToString();
        var mSQLTable = "[Staging].[tblLoadBUF]";

        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            string contents = File.ReadAllText(mFilepath, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));

            TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(new StringReader(contents));

            parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
            parser.SetDelimiters(",");

            string[] fields;

            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                fields = parser.ReadFields();

                if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
                {
                    foreach (string field in fields)
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field.Trim('\"')) ? null : field.Trim('\"'), typeof(string)));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(fields.Select(item => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Trim('\"')) ? null : item.Trim('\"')).ToArray());
                }


            }

            parser.Close();


            string connectionString = Dts.Connections["OLEDB_CONN"].ConnectionString;    //  ConnectionString will contain unsupported keywords like 'provider'
            connectionString = connectionString.Trim(';'); //  Remove the trailing semicolon so that when we perform the split in the following line, there are no index errors.
            var connStrDictionary = connectionString.Split(';').Select(x => x.Split('=')).ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);     //   Here we get each value-pair from connection string by splitting by ';', then splitting each element by '=' and adding the pair to a Dictionary.

            connectionString = "Data Source=" + connStrDictionary["Data Source"] + ";Initial Catalog=" + connStrDictionary["Initial Catalog"] + ";Integrated Security=" + connStrDictionary["Integrated Security"]; //  Build the actual connection string to be used.
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                {
                    sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = mSQLTable;
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Clear();
                    con.Open();

                    foreach (var column in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());
                    }

                    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                    con.Close();
                }
            }                    
            


            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Something went wrong ", ex.ToString(), string.Empty, 0);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }
    }
```

This was not working. Error received :
System.InvalidOperationException: The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination.

I did verified the input file column names as I know that they are case sensitive, and they are all the same. However, I really would like to get a turnaround to verify the source and destination columns, since the input files will be sent from many sources and we don't have any control on how they will be created...  with uppercase or lowercase variable names.

Can somebody help me solve this ? Pease note that English is not my primary language, so just let me know if this is not clear enough.  And thanks in advance for you help guys :-)

Mylene

Comment: What was the value it was trying to convert? Side point `a.Split(',')` is not the right way to read CSV files. Use a proper CSV parser instead.

Comment: @Charlieface My DataTable is created and populated as expected.  I did tried however to use a parser instead, and I did figured out the BulkImport Mapping...

Comment: What are the column names of the destination table? Your code uses `dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(i.ToString(), typeof(string)));` which means the columns will be called `1` `2` `3`. Perhaps you actually meant `dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(columns[i], typeof(string)));`

Comment: I did modified the code to use the following...

dt.Rows.Add(fields.Select(item => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Trim('\"')) ? null : item.Trim('\"')).ToArray());

Comment: I can see that my datatable is as I expect it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to do it ! You have to query the destination table to get the list of column. Here is the code if it can help somebody...

```
public void Main()
    {
        var mFilepath = Dts.Variables["InputFile"].Value.ToString();
        var mSQLTable = "[Staging].[tblLoadBUF]";
        string connectionString = Dts.Connections["OLEDB_CONN"].ConnectionString;
               connectionString = connectionString.Trim(';');
        var connStrDictionary = connectionString.Split(';').Select(x => x.Split('=')).ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
               connectionString = "Data Source=" + connStrDictionary["Data Source"] + ";Initial Catalog=" + connStrDictionary["Initial Catalog"] + ";Integrated Security=" + connStrDictionary["Integrated Security"];


        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string contents = File.ReadAllText(mFilepath, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));

            TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(new StringReader(contents));

            parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
            parser.SetDelimiters(",");

            string[] fields;

            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                fields = parser.ReadFields();

                if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
                {
                    foreach (string field in fields)
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field.Trim('\"')) ? null : field.Trim('\"'), typeof(string)));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(fields.Select(item => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Trim('\"')) ? null : item.Trim('\"')).ToArray());
                }


            }
            parser.Close();

            var columnNames = new List<string>();
            using (var cn = new SqlConnection() { ConnectionString = connectionString })
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand() { Connection = cn })
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = Dts.Variables["StagingTableGetColumnsScript"].Value.ToString();

                    cn.Open();

                    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        columnNames.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                    }
                    cn.Close();
                }
            }


            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {                   

                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                {
                    sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = mSQLTable;
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Clear();
                    con.Open();

                    foreach (var column in columnNames)
                    {
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());
                    }

                    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                    con.Close();
                }
            }


            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Something went wrong ", ex.ToString(), string.Empty, 0);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }
    }
```